# Deploying dependent smart contracts using Web3.js?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

On this Truffle web page you see the following code to deploy a smart contract with Web3.js:

http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/build_processes

```
// Step 1: Get a contract into my application
var json = require("./build/contracts/MyContract.json");

// Step 2: Turn that contract into an abstraction I can use
var contract = require("truffle-contract");
var MyContract = contract(json);

// Step 3: Provision the contract with a web3 provider
MyContract.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));

// Step 4: Use the contract!
MyContract.deployed().then(function(deployed) {
  return deployed.someFunction();
});
```

What would this code look like if MyContract.json was dependent on another smart contract?  For example, given a **2_deploy_contracts.js** Truffle deployment script file like this:

```
var ConvertLib = artifacts.require("./ConvertLib.sol");
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");
var Voting = artifacts.require("./Voting.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ConvertLib);
  deployer.link(ConvertLib, MetaCoin);
  deployer.deploy(MetaCoin);
  // Deploy the voting smart contract.
  deployer.deploy(Voting);
};
```

My questions are:

- I assume I would need to repeat the code involved with **Steps 1-3** in the code above for each of my smart contracts? (i.e. - *ConvertLib/MetaCoin/Voting*).
- Are there any other changes that I would need to make so that dependent code is available to the smart contracts that depend on it?  For example, making sure the *ConvertLib* contract code is available to the *MetaCoin* contract code?
- What is the Javascript equivalent of the *deployer.link()* statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume I would need to repeat the code involved with Steps 1-3 in
>   the code above for each of my smart contracts? (i.e. -
>   ConvertLib/MetaCoin/Voting).

If your `Voting` contract is dependent on `MetaCoin` contract, let's say if your `Voting` contract needed to `MetaCoin` to be already deployed and use it `address` in the `Voting` constructor, so the answer is: yes, I suggest you create another deploy file for each contract.

> Are there any other changes that I would need to make so that
>   dependent code is available to the smart contracts that depend on it?
>   For example, making sure the ConvertLib contract code is available to
>   the `MetaCoin` contract code?

In that case, it works for libraries AFAIK because the `MetaCoin` needs the `Library` to be deployed before, so the linking will basic assign an address of library to your contract. But `truffle` does some `handling` to make sure that assigning works. Interesting post about is [library-driven-development-in-solidity](https://blog.aragon.one/library-driven-development-in-solidity-2bebcaf88736).

> What is the Javascript equivalent of the deployer.link() statement?

Let's say you have a third file called `3_deploy_voting.js` and it is dependent on `MetaCoin` to be deployed.

```
var Voting = artifacts.require("./Voting.sol");
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Voting, MetaCoin.address);
};
```

Considering the previous migration already deployed the `MetaCoin` the `address` is already available to use and your `Voting` contract constructor looks like:

```
function Voting(address metaCoinAddress) public {...
```